# Change icon zoom in toolbar react-apexchart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, icons, apexcharts

is it possible that the icon on the toolbar in the react-apexchart package can be changed?

for example here I want to customize the zoom and reset icon on the toolbar menu on the apex chart
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `chart.toolbar.tools` keys, you can use a string instead of a boolean value to use custom images.

Example

```js
chart: {
  toolbar: {
    tools: {
      zoom: '<img src="/static/icons/zoom.png" width="20">',
      zoomin: true,
      zoomout: true,
      reset: '<img src="/static/icons/reset.png" width="20">'
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: Any ideas why this doesn't work for the 'selection' tool ? It works for all others?